# lattice in a 3 dimension region

Tags: general-topology

In a 3 dimension lattice, a random walker moves from origin. Let $a_n$ be the coordinate of the random walker in n-th steps. $a_0=(0,0,0)$

The random walker moves 6 directions with same probability in every steps with step size 1. It means, $a_1$ can be $(0,0,1),(0,0,-1),(0,1,0),(0,-1,0),(1,0,0),(-1,0,0)$ with probability of $1/6$

Let $a_n \equiv (X_n,Y_n,Z_n)$

Let $P(n) \equiv P(0<X_n,0<Y_n,0<Z_n,X_n<Y_n+Z_n)$

Prove or disprove that $P(n)$ is increasing when $n\geq3$.

Comment: what do u mean by $Y_n+$?

Comment: apologize. I edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

False.

$P(3)=P[a_3=(1,1,1)]=\frac{6}{6^3}\approx 0.0277$
$P(4)=P[a_4=(1,2,1) \text{ or } a_4=(1,1,2)]=\frac{12+12}{6^4}\approx 0.0185$
$P(5)\approx 0.040$
$P(6)\approx 0.029$

Comment: I think $lim_{n\to \infty}P(n)=1/8$

Comment: $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}P(n)$ is close to 0.098.